# Calculating cosine algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, trigonometry

I created this function `CalculateCos`:

```
int Factorial (long int n)
{
    long int r = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        r = r*i;    
    }   

    return r;
}

float CalculateVariable(int CVnumber, int CVloopCounter)
{
    float CVresult = 0;
    CVresult = pow(CVnumber, (CVloopCounter*2)) / (long int)Factorial(CVnumber*2);

    return CVresult;
}

float CalculateCos(int number)
{
    float result = 1;
    int loopCounter = 1;
    int minusOrPlus = 1;
    while(loopCounter <= precision && loopCounter <= 8)
    {
        if(!minusOrPlus)
        {
            result = result - CalculateVariable(number, loopCounter);
            printf("%f\n", result);
            minusOrPlus = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            result = result + CalculateVariable(number, loopCounter);
            printf("%f\n", result);
            minusOrPlus = 0;
        }
        loopCounter++;
      }
      return result;
}
```

The reason why I printf after the subtraction or adding, is because it gives me strange output, like:

```
Enter a number, for the cos function
6
1.000000
0.999997
1.000095
0.996588
1.122822
-3.421593
160.177368
-5729.385254
Result is: -5729.3852539
Official function result is:  0.9601703
```

Can you help me to get correct results on this?

**UPDATE:**

Now my solution is:

```
float CalculateCos(float number)
{
    float result = 0;
    float step = 1;
    int loopCounter = 1;

    while(loopCounter <= 5)
    {
        step = step * (-number) * number / (((2*loopCounter)-1)*((2*loopCounter)-2));
        result += step;
        loopCounter++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Help with what? You didn't even say what the problem is, let alone you haven't posted a self-contained example.

Comment: I'd think something is overflowing or underflowing.

Comment: Please keep the original code and add the new code as the updated part. It helps others to understand the context of your question.

Comment: You still really need to ask a _specific_ question :)

Comment: Your function seems to divide by zero. You can try:
double my_cos(double x)
{
 int q = (x * 180 / PI) / 360;
 x = ((x * 180 / PI)-q*360)*(PI / 180);
 double ans = 1, step = 1;
 int lc = 1;
 while (lc <= 20)
 {
  step = step*(-x)*x / ((2 * lc - 1)*(2 * lc));
  ans += step;
  lc++;
 }
 return ans;
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Current problem:

since your `Factorial` function returns `int` and you casts it to `long int`, its result is going to overflow even before the input goes to `16` in your case (14! > max_int).

You're calculating `cos` using Taylor series:

> cos(x) = 1 - x<sup>2</sup>/2! + x<sup>4</sup>/4! - x<sup>6</sup>/6!
>   + ...

I'm not going to write code. But there are some things wrong in your program, which can be fixed easily:

1. The input is in radian, so `number` should be a `float`.
2. Calculating each step of Taylor series using exponentiation and factorial separately leads to overflow very soon. The correct way is maintaining a `float` variable: `step = 1` at first and in k<sup>th</sup> loop iteration `step = step * (- x) * x / ((2*k-1)*(2*k))`. In this way, you simply add `step` to `result` in the loop and don't need `minusOrPlus` anymore.
3. The number of loop iterations is bounded by `8` which is too small, so the result could be not precise enough.
4. I don't see you use `precision` variable anywhere. It could be used to check precision of the result. For example, when `abs(step) < precision`, we're going to terminate the loop.

Comment: Sorry for my typo: it should be `2*k` rather than `2*k-2` (I updated my answer). And limit of `loopCounter` should be much bigger than `5`. Other than that, your code looks right. Try to test it and compare with built-in `cos` function.